# gsutil tool is not found while building ubuntu-1804 images using packer

Tags: 18.04, cloud, google

I am facing a weird problem. I am trying to create a custom Ubuntu 1804 image in GCP using Hashicorp Packer. I create an instance manually I can access the gsutil command but when I am trying to create it using packer I am getting a `gsutil command not found` error. Is this a known issue? Are there some workarounds you are aware of?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the package for [`gsutil` executable](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=gsutil) by

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gsutil
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the comment. I tired doing what you have suggested. I get a new error. It basically says 'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources. Then it tries to got to a few addresses which are returning a forbidden 403. These address are as follows:           http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu,  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu,   
        http://archieve.canonical.com/ubuntu   . Also says bionic-security InRelease is no longer signed. Failed to fetch

Comment: Please add full error messages to the original question above by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1277195/edit).